# SDN 3.3.0 vs 4.0.0.M1

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Working on two version of SDN ( 3.3.0 & 4.0.0 Milestone version), Following are the things that were observed while using String[], String[][].

in 3.3.0, able to to store the single/double array's to database will null values and can retrieve them in order.

But in 4.0.0 MV, only single array is supported but while reading the order is different and storing "null" is not supported.

As it's a milestone version this issue can be solved in the final version of SDN4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDN supports only single dimensional arrays (both 3.3 and 4), perhaps they are converted to something else in 3.3

Regarding nulls, Neo4j won't store them either.

The reading order has been fixed post M1, please try using a snapshot build - http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will update to the latest version.                                                                                      In SDN 3.3.0

created double array string :
  
   String[][] doubleArray;
   
assigned value :
   String[][] dobary = new String[3][3];
   dobary[0][1] = "45";

after saving the node, in web UI able to see this property as follows :
   doubleArray:null,45,null,null,null,null,null,null,nul
   
Reading the double Array, gives the result as : [[null, 45, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null]].


Unable to do the same with SDN 4.0 Milestone version.

Comment: In SDN 4, you can write a converter http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_conversion